# Xcode: How to extract data from programmatically added ui elements?

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

I'm hoping I can get some help on a small issue.

Part of my application's UI is dynamic, so I am adding UI elements programmatically and storing then in a NSMutableArray. I have two questions:

1) Why do I get null value when I try to do the following?

```
UITextField* field = [self.uiElementsForWorkItems objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"title: %@", field.text);
```

If these are value copies and not references, how come I am able to successfully call removeFromSuperview on them?

2) How can I retrieve values from programmatically added UI elements (i.e. UITextField.text value) AND have a way which allows me to identify which element it was?

I have seen the below solution but it does not give a way of accessing the elements data or identifying it:

```
[title addTarget:self action:@selector(handlerMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UITextField.tag property, to call a particular element without using an array. (just make sure that tag is unique) by calling

`UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[self viewWithTag: tagValue];`

Try using the UITextField delegate methods. Most often, you can manage with delegates and tags.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get null value when I try to do the following?

Probably because `field` is nil. If `field` pointed to a real UITextField, you'd get a (possibly empty) string from `field.text`. If it pointed to something that didn't have a `text` accessor, you'd crash. It'd help if we knew how `self.uiElementsForWorkItems` came to be and what it contains.

> How can I retrieve values from programmatically added UI elements

Same way as for any other UI element: you send it a message asking for the data that you want. In order to send a message, you'll need a pointer to the object. If you're creating these UI objects programmatically, you'll want either to hold onto a reference to each object when you create it (similar to an IBOutlet) or to give yourself a way to find the object later, such as assigning a unique value to its `tag` property.